# Multiplying an int by an int to give a float is returning 0 language is C

Tags: c

```
lotacao_abs = (viagens[j].lotacao / 100) * navios[i].capacidade;
```

`lotacao_abs` is a float, `viagens[j].lotacao` is an `int` from a structure (yes, it's got the correct value I've checked), `navios[i].capacidade` is also an `int` (also has the correct value I've checked).

What's happening is that the value of `lotacao_abs` is always `0`. The idea of this part of the code is to give me the absolute value instead of the percentage, `viajens[j].lotacao` has the percentage and `navios[j].capacidade` has the max capacity of the ship, lets say that the percentage is 68% and the max capacity is `34,000`, then `lotacao_abs` should be `23,120`, but it instead is `0`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are assigning to, `int / int` gives `int` so (say) `99 / 100` is `0`. Please cast one of the operands.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with simple variable names, for example `a`, `b`, `c`, or `i` for `int` and `f` for `float`, or descriptive names in English, not some other language.

Comment: There must be dozends of duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subexpression `viagens[j].lotacao/100` is performing integer division.  So if `viajens[j].lotacao` is less than 100 then the result will be 0.

One of the arguments has to have floating point type to perform floating point division.  The simplest way to do this is to use `100.0` which is a floating point constant instead of `100` which is an integer constant.

```
lotacao_abs=(viagens[j].lotacao/100.0) * navios[i].capacidade;
```

Comment: first thank you, second, apparently just changing the order to ´lotacao_abs=navios[i].capacidade * viajens[j].lotacao/100; ´ also solved it.

Comment: @pmigbarros you expose it to arithmetic overflow by doing that. If you want the answer as `float` it is better to compute it that way.

Comment: @pmigbarros Changing the order still makes all the arithmetic handle, so if you have `25 * 25 / 100` you get `6`. But `25 * 25 / 100.0` will get you `6.25`.